# Update /usr/local/lib library with Sparkle

Tags: macos, sparkle

A legacy macOS project installs some `*.dylib`s to /usr/local/lib.
If I understand correctly, the basic [Sprakle](https://sparkle-project.org/documentation/) setup does not update these libraries.

1. Is this correct?
2. If so, how can I make Sparkle update these files?

Answer (score 0):

You download locally and install them afterwards.